# Proper way of creating new accounts in passwordless systems

Tags: ssh, password

What is the proper way of delivering credentials in passwordless ssh systems (linux)? By passwordless I mean login using only SSH keys. Should I generate pair of ssh keys and deliver it to new user, or allow to login once using password and force (somehow) new user to generate ssh key or append existing public key?

Comment: [Related](http://superuser.com/questions/1053511/who-generates-the-keys). It depends on many factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should let the user generate the key pair, and send you the public key so that you can add it to the list of authorized keys for passwordless authentication. the user's private key is, well, private :-)

Comment: True, I don't know why I did not think about it.